# Application after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish, custom-error-pages

I have a asp.net application, that work like nothing, until I published it to IIS. It keeps on saying that I have to add *customerror* tag wich I did.

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errorpage/Booboo.aspx"/>
```

But it keeps on returning the runtime error page with in the url aspxpatherror. I've been googling all day to find the cause of this bug but i can't seem to find it.

```
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        string err = "<b>Error Caught in Page_Error event</b><hr><br>" +
                "<br><b>Error in: </b>" + Request.Url.ToString() +
                "<br><b>Error Message: </b>" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
                "<br><b>Stack Trace:</b><br>" +
                          objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
        Response.Write(err.ToString());
        Server.ClearError();
    }
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event\n" +
                "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                "\nError Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
                "\nStack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Sample_WebApp", err, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        Server.ClearError();
        //additional actions...
    }
```

this is my error page

Comment: which kind of error mention it?

Comment: Just runtime error , saying use customerrors thats it

Comment: @NicolasPierre then visit it through `http://localhost` or [enable remote errors](http://codesnob.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/remote-error-messages-iis/).

Comment: @nicolasPierre replace by this `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Errorpage/Booboo.aspx"/>` to `<customErrors mode="on" defaultRedirect="~/Errorpage/Booboo.aspx"/>
`

Comment: I tried both suggestions but it keeps returning the error page the link changes to this http://myserver:1990/Errorpage/Booboo.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/

Comment: This kind of error on your local host or on live site?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug but error in your own code. You need to set breakpoint and debug line by line.